# How to speed up REGEXP LEVEL query on Oracle SQLDeveloper

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, performance, insert-into

I have an `INSERT INTO SELECT` statement that populates a table with values parsed by a `;` in the source table:

```
INSERT INTO PC_MATERIALS_BRIDGE (MATERIAL_BRIDGE_ID, VARIABLE_ID, MATERIAL_NAME)
   SELECT PC_VAR_MATERIALS_BRIDGE_SEQ.NEXTVAL, VARIABLE_ID, MATERIAL_NAME FROM (SELECT DISTINCT E.VARIABLE_ID, LOWER(TRIM(REGEXP_SUBSTR(e.MATERIALS, '[^;]+', 1, LEVEL))) MATERIAL_NAME
        FROM (SELECT VARIABLE_ID, MATERIALS FROM SRC_VARS_OCEAN_ALL WHERE MATERIALS IS NOT NULL AND MATERIALS != 'N/A) e
        CONNECT BY LOWER(TRIM(REGEXP_SUBSTR(e.MATERIALS, '[^;]+', 1, LEVEL))) IS NOT NULL);
```

So, data in the source table

```
ID     MATERIAL_NAME
1      paper
2      paper; plastic
```

will appear as

```
MATERIAL_BRIDGE_ID     MATERIAL_NAME   
1                      paper
2                      paper
3                      plastic
```

in the target table.

The script runs fine; however, it is very expensive because the source table has nearly 40,000 records and some have three values, e.g., `paper; plastic; rubber`. I know `LEVEL` is expensive. I have `MATERIAL_NAME` set to `VARCHAR2(255 BYTE)`. Not sure how to improve other than writing another type of query (e.g., recursive but it's probably difficult). Is `DISTINCT` also causing it to slow down? The `DISTINCT` may not be necessary anymore because `e.VARIABLE_ID` is the primary key now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very inefficient method. You can observe why it causes problems when you remove DISTINCT in the below simple demo:

```
create table SRC_VARS_OCEAN_ALL(
  VARIABLE_ID int, 
  MATERIALS varchar2(200)
);

insert into SRC_VARS_OCEAN_ALL values( 1, 'ala;ma;kota' );
insert into SRC_VARS_OCEAN_ALL values( 2, 'as;to;pies' );
insert into SRC_VARS_OCEAN_ALL values( 3, 'baba;jaga' );
insert into SRC_VARS_OCEAN_ALL values( 4, 'zupa;obiad' );
```

and:

```
SELECT  E.VARIABLE_ID, level,
        LOWER(TRIM(REGEXP_SUBSTR(e.MATERIALS, '[^;]+', 1, LEVEL))) MATERIAL_NAME
FROM (
    SELECT VARIABLE_ID, MATERIALS 
    FROM SRC_VARS_OCEAN_ALL 
    WHERE MATERIALS IS NOT NULL 
    AND MATERIALS != 'N/A'
) e
CONNECT BY LOWER(TRIM(REGEXP_SUBSTR(e.MATERIALS, '[^;]+', 1, LEVEL))) IS NOT NULL
order by 1,2;

VARIABLE_ID      LEVEL MATERIAL_NAME     
----------- ---------- -----------------
          1          1 ala               
          1          2 ma                
          1          2 ma                
          1          2 ma                
          1          2 ma                
          1          3 kota              
          1          3 kota              
          1          3 kota              
          1          3 kota              
          1          3 kota              
          1          3 kota              
          1          3 kota              
          1          3 kota              
          1          3 kota              
          1          3 kota              
          1          3 kota              
          1          3 kota              
          1          3 kota              
          1          3 kota              
          1          3 kota              
          1          3 kota              
          2          1 as                
          2          2 to                
          2          2 to                
          2          2 to                
          2          2 to                
          2          3 pies              
          2          3 pies              
          2          3 pies              
          2          3 pies              
          2          3 pies              
          2          3 pies              
          2          3 pies              
          2          3 pies              
          2          3 pies              
          2          3 pies              
          2          3 pies              
          2          3 pies              
          2          3 pies              
          2          3 pies              
          2          3 pies              
          2          3 pies              
          3          1 baba              
          3          2 jaga              
          3          2 jaga              
          3          2 jaga              
          3          2 jaga              
          4          1 zupa              
          4          2 obiad             
          4          2 obiad             
          4          2 obiad             
          4          2 obiad             

52 rows selected.
```

---

This query generates **52 output records for only 4 input** rows with 10 values. You can guess how many will be for 40 thousand.
 The query generates hundreds of thausands or even millions of rows, then DISTINCT sorts this huge resultset in order to eliminate duplicates.

---

The below query should perform much better because it generates only 10 records, no more or less, just as much as needed to do this task:

```
SELECT  a.VARIABLE_ID, b.lev_el,
       trim( regexp_substr( a.MATERIALS, '[^;]+', 1, b.lev_el )) as MATERIAL_NAME
FROM SRC_VARS_OCEAN_ALL a
JOIN (
  SELECT level as lev_el
  FROM dual CONNECT BY level <= 100
) b
ON b.lev_el <= regexp_count( a.MATERIALS, ';' ) + 1

VARIABLE_ID     LEV_EL MATERIAL_NAME 
----------- ---------- --------------
          1          1 ala           
          2          1 as            
          3          1 baba          
          4          1 zupa          
          1          2 ma            
          2          2 to            
          3          2 jaga          
          4          2 obiad         
          1          3 kota          
          2          3 pies          

10 rows selected.
```

I am assumming that there is no more than 100 values in each list (each individual row has a list with no more than 100 values in it), so there is `FROM dual CONNECT BY level <= 100` clause.

Comment: Great, thanks. I had been using `DISTINCT` but overlooked the fact that sorts the rows after it has retrieved all possible rows. Cheers.